# get date day full name in snowflake

Tags: date, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema, snowflake-task

get date day full name in snowflake

I tried to use below query to get day name but giving short name only(3 Chars of day)

```
SELECT upper(trim(DAYNAME(CURRENT_DATE)))
```

**O/p: MON**

**Expected output: MONDAY**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the Snowflake date/time [examples](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/date-time-examples.html):

```
select decode(extract ('dayofweek_iso',current_date()),
  1, 'Monday',
  2, 'Tuesday',
  3, 'Wednesday',
  4, 'Thursday',
  5, 'Friday',
  6, 'Saturday',
  7, 'Sunday');
```

Alternatively:

```
select decode(DAYNAME(CURRENT_DATE), 'Mon','Monday', 'Tues','Tuesday', ...);

select object_construct('Mon','Monday', 'Tues','Tuesday', ...)[DAYNAME(CURRENT_DATE)];
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a more concise alternative approach:

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE Today, UPPER(TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE, 'DYDY')) Day_Full_Name
```

Output:

> ```
> |TODAY        |DAY_FULL_NAME |
> |2023-06-30   |FRIDAY        |
> ```

Comment: Giving SUNSUN as an output rather than SUNDAY

Comment: The query (as asked by the OP) given above works, but Snowflake appears to malfunction when you pass a column with a named/dynamic value expression instead of CURRENT_DATE (a static expression).