# Snowflake - Get full name of day in records

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I tried to change the `current_date()` from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60484104/get-date-day-full-name-in-snowflake) but I cannot make it work for records in a table. This is my query:

```
 select decode(extract('dayofweek_iso', LAST_MODIFIED_DATE),
  1, 'Monday',
  2, 'Tuesday',
  3, 'Wednesday',
  4, 'Thursday',
  5, 'Friday',
  6, 'Saturday',
  7, 'Sunday');
 FROM RTABLE
```

But it is returning `SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 39 invalid identifier 'LAST_MODIFIED_DATE'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you column `LAST_MODIFIED_DATE` does not appear to exist in your table `RTABLE`

```
select decode(extract ('dayofweek_iso',current_date()),
  1, 'Monday',
  2, 'Tuesday',
  3, 'Wednesday',
  4, 'Thursday',
  5, 'Friday',
  6, 'Saturday',
  7, 'Sunday');
```

works, because `current_date()` always exists.

and if I use some VALUES and thus COLUMN1 is valid:

```
select decode(extract ('dayofweek_iso',column1),
  1, 'Monday',
  2, 'Tuesday',
  3, 'Wednesday',
  4, 'Thursday',
  5, 'Friday',
  6, 'Saturday',
  7, 'Sunday')
from values 
  ('2013-05-08T23:39:20.123+00:00'::date),
  ('2014-05-08T23:39:20.123+00:00'::date),
  ('2015-05-08T23:39:20.123+00:00'::date)
    ;
```

gives:

| DECODE(EXTRACT ('DAYOFWEEK_ISO',COLUMN1), 1, 'MONDAY', 2, 'TUESDAY', 3, 'WEDNESDAY', 4, 'THURSDAY', 5, 'FRIDAY', 6, 'SATURDAY', 7, 'SUNDAY') |
| --- |
| Wednesday |
| Thursday |
| Friday |

```
 select decode(extract('dayofweek_iso', LAST_MODIFIED_DATE),
  1, 'Monday',
  2, 'Tuesday',
  3, 'Wednesday',
  4, 'Thursday',
  5, 'Friday',
  6, 'Saturday',
  7, 'Sunday')   /* ; <--- this needs to be removed */
 FROM RTABLE
```

Comment: it exists and is in timestamp format @simeonpilgrim

Comment: if I copy your SQL and replace just `LAST_MODIFIED_DATE` with `current_date()` if gives me Tuesday,... AHH there is a SEMICOLON after the end of the decode..

Comment: oh yes, haven't noticed that. works after the removal

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay with having 3 letters, `dayname` might come in more handy

```
select dayname(last_modified_date)
from t;
```